# Javascript : Show value behind

Tags: javascript, php

> What i try to achieve is make a number to show float point which is
>
> 1910 = 19.10

```
 var totals2 = [0, 0, 0];
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $dataRows2 = $("#dataTable2 tr:not('.totalColumn2, .titlerow2')");
      $dataRows2.each(function() {
        $(this).find('.rowDataSd2').each(function(i) {
          totals2[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
        });
      });


      $("#dataTable2 td.totalCol2").each(function(i) {


        $(this).html( totals2[i]);
      });
});
```

But with this code i'm aware it give me result:
 19 instead of 19.10

Comment: parseInt() will give int value always.

Comment: You are using parseInt, you cannot get a float. Please show us your HTML structure or a sample of your data.

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: use parseFloat against ParseInt and toFixed(2) for totals2[i]

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). __`totals2[i] += +$(this).text();`__ should solve your problem...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jzpxo5y6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary.php

```
            <thead>
              <tr class="titlerow2">     

                <th>Merchant Id</th>
                <th>Txn Count </th>
                <th>Retail</th>
                <th>Cashout</th>
                <th>Total</th>
              </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php foreach ( $ISOMX as $ISO ): ?> 
              <tr>             
              <td width="5%"><?php echo  ebcdic_to_ascii($ISO["mid"]); ?></td>
              <td width="5%"><?php  echo $ISO["TxtCount"]; ?> </td>

              <td class="rowDataSd2" width="5%"><?php echo   number_format($ISO["CASHOUT"] / 100, 2, '.', ''); ?></td>
              <td class="rowDataSd2" width="5%"><?php echo   number_format($ISO["RETAIL"] / 100, 2, '.', ''); ?></td>
              <td class="rowDataSd2" width="5%"><?php echo   number_format($ISO["TOTAL"] / 100, 2, '.', ''); ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>    
              <tr class="totalColumn2">
              <td></td>
              <td>Grand Total (RM): </td>
              <td class="totalCol2"></td>
              <td class="totalCol2"></td>
              <td class="totalCol2"></td>


             </tr>
          </table>
```

Javascript

```
var totals2 = [0, 0, 0];
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var $dataRows2 = $("#dataTable2 tr:not('.totalColumn2, .titlerow2')");
          $dataRows2.each(function() {
            $(this).find('.rowDataSd2').each(function(i) {
              totals2[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
          });


          $("#dataTable2 td.totalCol2").each(function(i) {


            $(this).html( totals2[i]);
          });
    });
```